# Can you use Dark Sign and still get Illusory Ring of a Conqueror?

Tags: dark-souls-2-sotfs

Can you use [Dark Sign](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Darksign) and still get [Illusory Ring of a Conqueror](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Illusory+Ring+of+a+Conqueror)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line of the Darksign description:

> ***Kills you***...

And from the Illlusory Ring:

> Clear the game ***without dying***...

So no, you can't use the Darksign and still get the ring.

This can be proven in several ways. Firstly, the wiki description states that the Darksign works similar to dying, except without leaving a bloodstain - you lose all souls when you use it. Secondly, if you disconnect from the internet, the monument in Majula will become a personal death counter. Each use of the Darksign increases it by 1. And finally, the first time you use it, you will become hollowed, and each following use will reduce your overall HP.

Comment: Dark souls descriptions are know to be imprecise. Have you (or someone else) actually tested what you say here?

Comment: @klm123 Yes. You can test this by disconnecting from the internet, and visiting the monument in Majula - it will show you your death counter. Each use of the Darksign increases it by 1

Comment: Additionally, those descriptions are taken from the wiki, not the item description.